# Generating Sparse Grids with Non-negative Weights

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, sparse-matrices

I've been looking for Matlab code to generate a sparse grid with positive weights.

I've found a variety of codes for this used in numerical integration found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19063-sparse-grid-quadrature/content/spquad.m) and [here](http://sparse-grids.de/).

For example the documentation on sparse-grids.de states for the Gauss-Hermite rule the weighting function is $w(x) = \exp\{-x'x/2\}/\sqrt{2\pi}>0$, and yet returns weights that oscillate in sign.

Can anyone with a better knowledge of quadrature rules explain to me why these programs are outputting negative weights? For my application (approximating a stochastic process by a Markov-chain), I need to generate a sparse grid with all positive weights.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need this kind of rule for a specific dimension?

Comment: And, more important, what order of polynomial exactness do you need?

Comment: Yes, I need specifically 24 dimensions. I am not sure what degree polynomial I need, as I am trying to approximate a mixed-normal distribution which doesn't have a known functional form.